# IF/ELSE makes stored procedure not return a result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that needs to return something from one of two databases:

```
IF @x = 1
    SELECT y FROM Table_A
ELSE IF @x = 2
    SELECT y FROM Table_B
```

Either `SELECT` alone will return what I want, but adding the `IF`/`ELSE` makes it stop returning anything. I tried:

```
IF @x = 1
    RETURN SELECT y FROM Table_A
ELSE IF @x = 2
    RETURN SELECT y FROM Table_B
```

But that causes a syntax error.

The two options I see are both horrible:

1. Do a `UNION` and make sure that only one side has any results:

   SELECT y FROM Table_A WHERE @x = 1
   UNION
   SELECT y FROM Table_B WHERE @x = 2
2. Create a temporary table to store one row in, and create and delete it every time I run this procedure (lots).

Neither solution is elegant, and I assume they would both be horrible for performance (unless MS SQL is smart enough not to search the tables when the WHERE class is always false).

Is there anything else I can do? Is option 1 not as bad as I think?

Comment: Are you sure @x is equal to 1 or 2?

Comment: Yes, `@x` is hard coded elsewhere (and if it's wrong I want a scary error message).

Comment: Are you sure the select statments on their own are really returning what you want?  IN Sql Server your select @y from Table_A would just return whatever the value is in @y for the number or rows in table_a

Comment: The actual stored procedure is much more complicated, I left out anything that didn't matter (apparently with some mistakes).

Comment: Just a thought. You mention "one of two databases".  Are you sure Table_A and Table_B are qualified correctly?  How is it that you're confirming that the queries run correctly when not in the IF/ELSE?

Have you just tried debugging the SP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you sure that @x is 1 or 2?

```
declare @x int

set @x = 1

IF @x = 1
    SELECT 'syscolumns',* FROM syscolumns
ELSE IF @x = 2
    SELECT 'sysobjects',* from sysobjects
    else
    select 'not 1 or 2'
```

BTW what is this line supposed to do

```
SELECT @y FROM Table_B
```

it will just return the same variable @y for however many rows you have in TableB

based on you comment, 0 means success, the proc did not error out. Don't use a return statement, use an output parameter instead

based on your second comment you can use this, note this will only work in a proc since inline sql cannot use the return statement

```
declare @y int,@x int
select @y = -500


IF @x = 1
    SELECT  @y = y FROM Table_A
ELSE IF @x = 2
    SELECT  @y = y FROM Table_B

return @y
```

Comment: yes a return value of 0 means success, this has nothing to do with the resultset, it is the error code

Comment: How do I make it return the result set and not the error code?

Comment: you can't, a return statement can only 'return' an int, just use a select statement, if you run the code I provided you will see a result set

Comment: Uh yeah.. so apparently the `@x = 1` part was the problem after all.

Answer (score 3):

Some ideas:

First, why the "else"?

```
IF @x = 1 
    SELECT y FROM Table_A 
IF @x = 2 
    SELECT y FROM Table_B
```

should do what you want without the worries of nesting, block declaration (BEGIN/END), and the like.

Second, any chance that @x is null? If it were, neither query would run.

Third, for a "scary message", add something like this after the above two lines:

```
IF isnull(@x, 0) not in (1,2)
    RAISERROR('Data invalid, reformatting C:\', 20, 1)
```

(Ok, you could have a better error message, but that'd sure scare me...)